# Trouble Parsing Date with SimpleDateFormat due to "T" Character

Tags: java, android

```
2015-11-03T17:33:27
```

I currently get the above date as a String from a JSON call. The problem is, I have no idea how to parse the T in between the 3 and the 17. When I use SimpleDateFormat, shown below, I keep getting unparseable date. What exactly do I do with the T here?

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
messageDate = format.parse(recentMessage.getJSONObject("message_data").getString("sent_at"));
```

Comment: Can you add what you get from `recentMessage.getJSONObject("message_data").getString("sent_at")` and the full error that you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date messageDate = format.parse("2015-11-03T17:33:27".replace("T", " "));
```

Also keep Timezone in mind when parsing the dates.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks